# Dual monitor 4k 60hz with only 1 displayport

Tags: hdmi, displayport

I recently purchased 2 4k monitors for my PC which has a R9 380. The 380 only has 1 displayport and 1 hdmi, so on the monitor that is connected via hdmi I am only getting 30hz and some mouse lag. Am I stuck with this limitation and would need a new graphics card to get 60hz on both monitors or is there something I can do to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Super User!

Unfortunately, it seems that the R9-380 graphics card has a HDMI version 1.4 port, which does not support 4k@60 Hz. This type of connection can at most support a resolution of 4096x2160@24 Hz. As you noticed, the DisplayPort (version 1.2) on your card is able to handle 4096x2160@60 Hz without a problem, however the version of HDMI present on your card cannot (You can read more about the different HDMI and DisplayPort versions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.4) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#1.2)).

Now, some versions of the R9-380 ([like this one](https://www.msi.com/Graphics-card/R9-380-GAMING-4G/Specification)) have two DVI ports in addition to a HDMI and DisplayPort, which are capable of outputting 2560x1600 @60 Hz, however you stated in your question that your card does not have these two other connections, and *"only has 1 displayport and 1 hdmi."*

Based on the fact that one of the two connections on your card does not support 4k@60Hz, I cannot think of anyway it would be possible to drive two monitors with this resolution. Purchasing a new card is likely the most viable option.